# In laravel 6, queue is being stopped automatically after executing few jobs but not all

Tags: laravel

I'm creating few jobs through a command, jobs are saving in DB's jobs table but while i'm running `php artisan queue:work` command, queue is being stopped after executing few jobs. all jobs are not being executed. no errors in log file. Anyone can help me to trace out the reason ? I've tried by increasing timeout value as `php artisan queue:work --timeout=300` but still not working.

*Update*

Job class

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class CreateContent implements ShouldQueue
{
    public $contentType;

    public function __construct($type)
    {
        $this->contentType = $type;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->generateContentData($this->contentType);
    }

    // generate
    public function generateContentData($content_type)
    {
        $resource = str_replace("_", "", ucwords($content_type->name, " /_"));

        // process table name
        $source_table = 'npf content ' . $content_type->name;
        $source_table = str_replace(' ', '_', $source_table);
        $source_domain_table = $source_table . '_domain';
        $tenant_table = 'np contents ' . $content_type->name;
        $tenant_table = str_replace(' ', '_', $tenant_table);

        $data = DB::connection('source')
            ->table($source_table)
            ->join($source_domain_table, $source_table . '.id', '=', $source_domain_table . '.node_id')
            ->select($source_table . '.*', $source_domain_table . '.domain_id')
            ->get();


        // transform data
        $transformer = "\\App\\Http\\Resources\\Contents\\{$resource}Resource";
        // collect data
        $content_data = $transformer::collection($data)->chunk(500);
        // process content data
        foreach ($content_data as $data) {

            // insert content data
            DB::connection('tenant')->table($tenant_table)->upsert($data['content'], 'id');
            // insert file data
            if (!empty($data['file'])) {
                DB::connection('tenant')->table('system_files')->upsert($data['file'], 'id');
            }
            // insert translate data
            DB::connection('tenant')->table('rainlab_translate_attributes')->upsert($data['translate'], 'id');
        }
    }
}
```

**Queue Config**

QUEUE_CONNECTION=database

**Job Dispatch**

Jobs are dispatching through a command

```
...
foreach ($content_types as $content_type) 
{
   dispatch(new CreateContent($content_type));
}
```

Comment: Please add the Job class, Queue configuration and the code to dispatch the jobs

Comment: After running queue:work command, you will see the logs like 'Processing...' then 'Processed'. So, if you have 3 jobs then you will see these logs 3 times. Question is, when you said "queue is being stopped after executing few jobs" - is your queue:work command terminating itself? Try this... after finishing few jobs try to dispatch few more jobs and then check the queue:work logs.

Comment: @Saly3301 info updated.

Comment: @Digvijay . yes queue:work terminating itself. say i ahve 100 jobs. after executing 20 jobs for example it terminating itself. i have to run queue:work again & again to complete all jobs. but no error in logs.

Comment: @ArifHossain Try this as a temporary solution php artisan queue:work --stop-when-empty

Comment: @Digvijay `php artisan queue:work --stop-when-empty` don't resolve the issue.